# How can I read, write and modify the user.json file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I have deployed a next.js app.
I implemented the member registration function to respond to the request sent from the front using next.js api routes.
In the local environment, it was successful when sending a membership registration request, but after deploying to vercel, a 500 error occurs.
I want to save member information even after distribution.
please help me to solve this problem

```
// components/auths/SignUpModal.tsx

...

    const onSubmitSignUp = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const signUpBody = {
                email,
                lastname,
                firstname,
                password,
                birthday: new Date(
                    `${birthYear}-${birthMonth!.replace('월', '')}-${birthDay}`
                ).toISOString(),
            };
            signupAPI(signUpBody);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

...
```

```
// lib/api/index.ts
import Axios from 'axios';

const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL,
});

export default axios;
```

```
// lib/api/auth.ts
import axios from 'axios';

interface SignUpAPIBody {
    email: string;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    password: string;
    birthday: string;
}

export const signupAPI = (body: SignUpAPIBody) => {
    axios.post('api/auth/signup', body);
};
```

```
// pages/api/auth/signup.ts
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import Data from '../../../lib/data';
import { StoredUserType } from '../../../types/user';

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const { email, firstname, lastname, password, birthday } = req.body;
        if (!email || !firstname || !lastname || !password || !birthday) {
            res.statusCode = 400;
            return res.send('필수 데이터가 없습니다.');
        }
        const userExist = Data.user.exist({ email });
        if (userExist) {
            res.statusCode = 409;
            return res.send('이미 가입된 이메일입니다.');
        }

        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);
        const users = Data.user.getList();
        let userId;
        if (users.length === 0) {
            userId = 1;
        } else {
            userId = users[users.length - 1].id + 1;
        }
        const newUser: StoredUserType = {
            id: userId,
            email,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            password: hashedPassword,
            birthday,
            profileImage: '/static/image/default_user_profile_image.jpg',
        };
    

        Data.user.write([...users, newUser]);

        const token = jwt.sign(String(newUser.id), 'my_private_secret');
        const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 * 3);
        res.setHeader(
            'Set-Cookie',
            `access_token=${token};path=/expires=${expires.toUTCString()};httponly`
        );
        res.statusCode = 200;
        return res.send(newUser);
    }
    res.statusCode = 405;

    return res.end();
};
```

```
// lib/data/user.ts
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { StoredUserType } from '../../types/user';

const getList = () => {
    const usersBuffer = readFileSync('data/users.json');
    const usersString = usersBuffer.toString();
    if (!usersString) {
        return [];
    }
    const users: StoredUserType[] = JSON.parse(usersString);
    return users;
};

const exist = ({ email }: { email: string }) => {
    const users = getList();
    return users.some((user) => user.email === email);
};

const write = async (users: StoredUserType[]) => {
    writeFileSync('data/users.json', JSON.stringify(users));
};

export default { getList, exist, write };
```

```
// data/users.json
```

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data/users.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:468:35)
    at getList (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/signup.js:31:67)
    at Object.exist (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/signup.js:45:17)
    at signup (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/signup.js:83:33)
    at Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:488:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:751:37)
    at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:253:36) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'data/users.json'
}
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data/users.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:468:35)
    at getList (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/signup.js:31:67)
    at Object.exist (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/signup.js:45:17)
    at signup (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/auth/signup.js:83:33)
    at Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:488:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:751:37)
    at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:253:36) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'data/users.json'
}
RequestId: 161d1ce4-2d12-4a36-8197-8463b6a18e70 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

I tried using google search but couldn't solve this problem...
No matter how much I search for 5 days, I can't find any related articles, so I'm asking for help...

Answer (score 0):

The file system `fs` will not be available in Next.js Serverless functions. You will have to use an external database to persist any data.

It might work when developing locally, but definitely not when deployed.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. It's something that couldn't be solved with next.js alone...
Thank you for making it clear.

Comment: Can I persist data by just creating an external database?
Do I need to deploy the next.js api routes code separately?

Comment: @seoyoon Setup an external serverless database and then connect to this one through HTTP from your api routes. If you know MySQL, Planetscale.com can be used with serverless functions.